# Add a specific cell in excel to email body VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I currently have a code that will generate an email based on the coming due date.  Below is the example of my table. 
[Image of Excel Table][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYhlD.png.  My code works to populate an email but I want to state the ID, Description, assigned to, and due date into the email field.  Can someone help?

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long

Dim x As Long
With Sheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow

mydate1 = Cells(x, 7).Value
mydate2 = mydate1

Cells(x, 37).Value = mydate2

datetoday1 = Date
datetoday2 = datetoday1

Cells(x, 36).Value = datetoday2

If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 10 Then


Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mymail.To = Cells(x, 31).Value
mymail.CC = Cells(x, 32).Value


With mymail
.Subject = "Payment Reminder"
.Body = "Please close your ICAR  by due date"
.Display
'.send
End With

Cells(x, 33) = “Yes”
Cells(x, 33).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(x, 33).Font.ColorIndex = 2
Cells(x, 33).Font.Bold = True
Cells(x, 33).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2
End If

Next
Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To get the Id Number on Email body, see example*

```
Dim x As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lastrow As Long
With Sht
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow

        .Cells(x, 37).Value = mydate2
         Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
         Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Dim IDnumber As String
        IDnumber = .Cells(x, 1).Value

        Debug.Print IDnumber ' print on immediate Window

        With mymail
            .Subject = "Payment Reminder"
            .Body = "ID Number " & IDnumber
            .Display
            '.send
        End With

        .Cells(x, 33) = "Yes"
        .Cells(x, 33).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        .Cells(x, 33).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Cells(x, 33).Font.Bold = True
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I like creating what I want in Excel, then importing it.

```
SubjectTemp = wb.names("NamedRange!").Referstorange.value2
```

--

```
With mymail
.Subject = SubjectTemp
.Body = "Please close your ICAR  by due date"
.Display
'.send
End With
```

--

```
="My email subject is to "&$A$1
```

This sets the subject as "My email subject is to" and whatever is in A1.

Rinse and repeat for all of the fields.

It allows for easy editing inside of Excel without needing to go into VBA.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying.  I am not understanding this, I have a specific cell and if that is true, then it will make an email.  In the email, I want to have certain cells from the true statement to be populated in the body of the email.

Comment: Ok. I'm using a named range to store data in Excel. The actual data is from formulas and typing you do in Excel. From there, I import the data into Excel with the first line, the subjecttemp. I then use the data I've pulled to fill in the email subject field. This can be repeated for the body, attachements, etc.

Comment: Hello, Im still not understanding...can you try putting it in my code for at least ID number?